# Login button is not working for Xamarin Android app

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I can't fire my login button with the web service. After pressing login button, nothing happens. Please help 
Below is my code for the login page:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    userName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUser);
    pass = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
    login = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin);
    error = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.error);
    reg = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.register);
    login.Click += delegate
    {
        AuthWebService.MemberService ws = new AuthWebService.MemberService();
        AuthWebService.AuthHeader authentication = new AuthWebService.AuthHeader();
        authentication.Username = "example";
        authentication.Password = "example";
        ws.AuthHeaderValue = authentication;
        bool bRet = ws.RequestMemberLogin(1, userName.Text, pass.Text, "", "");
        ws.RequestMemberLoginCompleted += Ws_LoginCompleted;

        void Ws_LoginCompleted(object s, AuthWebService.RequestMemberLoginCompletedEventArgs E)
        {
            if (bRet == true)
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(datalist));
            }
            else
            {
                error.Text = "Invalid username or password";
            };
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you must use

```
ws.RequestMemberLoginCompleted += Ws_LoginCompleted;
```

before

```
bool bRet = ws.RequestMemberLogin(1, userName.Text, pass.Text, "", "");
```

Comment: but if add ws.RequestMemberLoginCompleted += Ws_LoginCompleted; before bRet then the bRet is unassigned

Comment: You're right, and that's the reason you can't use bRet in your callback function. The information you need should be in your event args parameter E. Use that instead.

Comment: means i have to assign like E.Result == true in the if condition?

Comment: That depends entirely what your RequestMemberLoginCompletedEventArgs are. It's unlikely to be a boolean. Without knowing what your AuthWebService actually is, there's no way I can say for sure. Also, you probably should move your Ws_LoginCompleted method outside of the delegate.